# How to update destination url via api in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I want to update the default destination url via api how can I do that?
I did try to update it in UI and sent a request to get this brand. But there is no details about this url that I've just added.

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DocuSign API Documentation -
 AccountBrands: update](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/AccountBrands/update/)

You should be able to use `landingPages` for that (empty string to return to default behavior)

```
"landingPages": [
  {
    "name": "signingComplete",
    "value": "https://www.google.com/"
  },
  {
    "name": "viewingComplete",
    "value": "https://www.google.com/"
  },
  {
    "name": "finishLater",
    "value": "https://www.google.com/"
  },
  {
    "name": "decline",
    "value": "https://www.google.com/"
  },
  {
    "name": "sessionTimeout",
    "value": "https://www.google.com/"
  },
  {
    "name": "failedAuthorization",
    "value": "https://www.google.com/"
  }
],
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I will try it

Comment: It works. Btw I didn't get the last updated brand (as seen in attached image) until I sent this put request to update it.

Comment: @NikD good to hear. Can you accept this as an answer so others can use? A lot of the defaults are hidden in GET brands, I'm not sure on the reasoning.